# How do you hide the first element in the first table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I know that to hide the first element in a table is simply do (':first-child') but is there a way to specify that only the first element of the first TABLE needs to be removed?

In my situation the first element of every table is being hidden and I need to fix this.

Comment: Are you looking to do this in plain JavaScript (i.e. no CSS or jQuery)?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you just target the first table, and then the first element, whatever that is ?

```
document.querySelector('table tr').style.display = 'none';
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/dhUh9/)

as querySelector gets the first matching element, or in jQuery

```
$('table:first tr:first').hide()
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/dhUh9/2/)

Comment: Might want to note that this requires jQuery.

Comment: @j08691 - didn't notice the missing jQuery tag

Answer (score 0):

You can get a collection of all tables using `document.getElementsByTagName("table")`.  Element zero of that collection ([0]) is the first table.  You can then apply your first-child solution to element zero.

This does not require jQuery, nor that you assign an ID attribute to a specific table.  (Assigning an ID attribute is probably more efficient if you know in advance which table is going to be first.)

Edited to add: I've tested this and it works, although it is revised from my first "it works" post.  The first child element of TABLE is TBODY for a table that starts with a `tr` element, so what is really wanted is the first child of TBODY.  It is probably better to descend the firstElementChild tree looking exspressly for a nodeName of "TR" and hide that.  Look further down in this post for that approach.

Here is the simple code that works:
`document.getElementsByTagName("table")[0].firstElementChild.firstElementChild.style.display = "none";`

This is pure JavaScript, with no need for jQuery.  Note that document.getElementsByTagName returns a live collection, so even if a table is added to the DOM, this will get the first one.

Do remember that the first element child of `<table>` (and then TBODY) is not necessarily `<tr>`.  If you can be sure it is, or if you want the first element regardless, then what I've given will work for you.  If you want to be sure it's a `<tr>` then a little more work will be needed.

This code finds and hides the first `<tr>` but will be less efficient because it gets two HTML collections:
`document.getElementsByTagName("table")[0].getElementsByTagName("tr")[0].style.display = "none";`

Answer (score 0):

target the first `table` and the first `td`.

```
 $('table:first td:first').hide()
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/4jy8s/1/)

Answer (score 0):

```
const tables = document.getElementsByTagName("table")
const firstTable = tables[0];
const firstRow = firstTable.rows[0];
firstRow.style.visibility = "hidden"; //hide
firstRow.style.visibility = "visible"; //visible
```

[Here is a referrence.](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/coll_table_rows.asp)